# MSVC 2005 linker memory consumption problem

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

I have an unusual problem. In the company where I work we have a lot of source code in our codebase, plus we use a lot of 3rd-party libraries. We're using MSVC 2005.

The problem is that linking our executable is very time-consuming (several minutes). Plus the memory usage of the linker reaches **1.7 GB**, whereas the final executable is "just" 22 MB.

We don't use /ltcg (link-time code generation) option.

I guess that linker loads at once all the OBJs and LIBs of all the dependencies. But OTOH this is not actually necessary: one may first load just all the raw symbols (without the corresponding code), build the dependencies tree. And then, using this tree, load only the relevant pieces of the code.

Does anybody know if the linker behavior can be changed? Perhaps there exists a corresponding linker option.
Is this fixed in MSVC 2008/2010?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe not the answer you are looking for, but consider moving all .lib to .dll. Correponding libs would become miniscule, which would speed up the linking process.

Comment: You're right, we consider this option. This will however impose other problems, like all the mess with versions of all the DLLs. Thanks.

Comment: I am probably wrong but is this something for you ? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ddperf/archive/2010/04/29/your-visual-studio-2010-dream-machine.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I second the comment that says to use DLLs. The DLL version issues that plagued Windows for a long time have, IMO, been resolved with the Side by Side assembly system.

If it's available in Visual Studio 2005, try enabling incremental linking.